# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/ | Django

Tags: django, paypal, django-rest-framework, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am having problems with django-paypal, the problem occurs at the moment of receiving the paypal IPN when the payment is successfully completed.

**Error:**

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/
[15/Sep/2019 22:53:04] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2896
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/
[15/Sep/2019 22:53:19] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2896
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/
[15/Sep/2019 22:53:42] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2896
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/
[15/Sep/2019 22:54:24] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2896
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /paypal/
[15/Sep/2019 22:55:45] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2896
```

I don't know what is happening, I started to investigate the error but I did not achieve much, investigating I put in the file `settings.py` `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` as `True`, and even then it did not work, any solution ?.

---

This is the code that makes the payment:

```
def process_payment(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk = pk)
    host = request.get_host()

    paypal_dict = {
        'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        'item_name': course.title,
        'amount': course.price,
        'currency_code': 'USD',
        'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        'return_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('course:list')),
        'cancel_return': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('payment_cancelled')),
    }

    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial = paypal_dict)
    return render(request, 'carts/process_payment.html', {'form': form, 'course': course})
```

---

**UPDATE**

The view that gives error was not made by me, is from django-paypal, which is responsible for managing the paypal IPN, the view is called `ipn`. The view is as follows:

https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/ipn/views.py

That view is the `notify_url`.

For more information, this is the guide I am doing: https://overiq.com/django-paypal-integration-with-django-paypal/

These are the urls.py of my application:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', CartDetailView.as_view(), name = 'cart'),
    path('cart-add/', views.add_course, name = 'add_course'),
    path('process-payment/<int:pk>/', views.process_payment, name='process_payment'),
    path('payment-cancelled/', views.payment_canceled, name='payment_cancelled'),

]
```

These are the urls.py of the `django-paypal` `ipn` application

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ipn, name="paypal-ipn"),
]
```

This would be my urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Paths of My Apps
    path('admin/', include(administration_patterns)),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('', include('carts.urls')),
    path('', include(course_patterns)),
    path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),

    # Paths of Auth
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
]
```

Comment: What code are you running to make this request?

Comment: I already updated my question with the code

Comment: Please update your question with the `urls.py` that processes the `/paypal/` path, and I'll update my answer in the morning.  thanks

Comment: Or you could link a github project and that would make it much easier (remember to remove api keys first!)

Comment: Ok, now update my question, verify, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added another update.  See if that works.

Comment: I already managed to solve the error thanks to the response of @Daniel Hepper, thanks in the same way for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the Paypal URL pattern to the top to ensure that the request is actually routed to `django-paypal`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Paths of My Apps
    path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
    path('admin/', include(administration_patterns)),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('', include('carts.urls')),
    path('', include(course_patterns)),

    # Paths of Auth
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
]
```

**Why are you seeing this error?**

The request is then routed to a view, which is not `csrf_exempt`, so the CSRF middleware expects a CSRF cookie.

As the request is sent from the Paypal server, it does not contain a CSRF cookie, so you are getting the error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`

**Why is the request routed to the wrong view?**

Patterns are matched in a depth-first approach, meaning Django first tries all patterns included from `'core.urls'`, `'carts.urls'` and `course_patterns` before trying to match `path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls'))`

One of the included URL patterns matches the path `/paypal/`, maybe something like `path('<slug>/', course_view)` in `course_patterns`.

Moving `path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),` up in the `urlpatterns` list ensures that Django tries to match it first.

Comment: Thank you!! that was the mistake !! although I don't know why ... in the same way thanks!

Comment: I've extended my answer to explain why you are seeing this particular error

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a [csrf token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) on the template where your form is rendered.

```
<form method="POST" action="/"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

</form>
```

### Update

You need to make the view that is processing `/paypal/` csrf exempt.  I assume that view is where paypal tries to redirect the user to after a payment is made:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def paypal_view(req):
...
```

### Update 2

Try this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', csrf_exempt(views.ipn), name="paypal-ipn"),
]
```

Comment: I already did it, that is not the problem, the problem is the view ... that view does not render any template, it is responsible for managing the paypal IPN ...

Comment: @JulioCesar Can you show the views/urls for `notify_url`?  You probably just need to make it `csrf_exempt`

Comment: Or whatever view is processing `/paypal/`, which is where your errors are.

Comment: Here is the source code of django-paypal, this is the view that manages the IPN: https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/ipn/views.py

Comment: That view is the `notify_url` (`ipn`)